# How To Replace or Write the Sentence Backwards

Tags: vb.net

I would like to have a block of code or a function in vb.net which can write a sentence backwards.

**For example** : i love visual basic

**Result** : basic visual love i

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim name As String 
Dim namereversed As String 
name = RichTextBox1.Text 
namereversed = "" 
Dim i As Integer 
For i = Len(name) To 1 Step -1 
namereversed = namereversed & Replace(name, i, 1) 
Next 
RichTextBox2.Text = namereversed
```

The code works but it does not give me the value of what i want. it makes the whole words reversed.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: `Dim name As String
        Dim namereversed As String
        name = RichTextBox1.Text
        namereversed = ""
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = Len(name) To 1 Step -1
            namereversed = namereversed & Replace(name, i, 1)
        Next
        RichTextBox2.Text = namereversed `

The code works  but it does not give me the value of what i want.
it makes the whole words reversed.

Comment: Please don't dump a bunch of unformatted code in a comment. Edit your question to make clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have edited it  . please any help

Comment: `namereversed = string.Join(" ", name.Split(" ").Reverse())`

Comment: String.Split will give you the words in the sentence. From there it should be easy to figure out.

Comment: What are your rules? Can you assume that there is a space between every "word"? Is there any punctuation? If so, how do you treat it? For example if the string is "One, two and three", do you want "three and two One,"?

Comment: thanks alot i really appericate u  sorry for my bad english ,

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim name As String = "i love visual basic"
    Dim reversedName As String = ""
    Dim tempName As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To name.Length - 1
        If Not name.Substring(i, 1).Trim.Equals("") Then
            tempName += name.Substring(i, 1)
        Else
            reversedName = tempName + " " + reversedName
            tempName = ""
        End If
    Next
```

start from index 0 and deduct 1 from length because length count starts with one but index count starts with zero. if you put `To name.Length` it will return `IndexOutOfBounds`. Loop it from `0 To Length-1` because you need the word as is and not spelled backwards... what are placed in reverse are the words so add a temporary String variable that stores every word and add it before the saved sentence/words.

or use this

```
Dim strName As String() = name.Split(" ")
Array.Reverse(strName)
reversedName = String.Join(" ", strName)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my contribution, well as you can see its not hard to do, its really simple. There are a lot of other ways which are more short.

```
    Console.Title = "Text Reverser"
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green

    'Text which will be Reversed
    Dim Text As String
    Console.Write("Write your text: ")
    Text = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Clear()

    Dim RevText As String = "" '← The Text that will be reversed
    Dim Index As Int32 = Text.Length '← Index used to write backwards

    'Fill RevText with a char
    Do Until RevText.Length = Text.Length
        RevText = RevText.Insert(0, "§")
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine(RevText)

    'Replace "Spaces" with Character, using 'Index' to know where go the chars
    For Each Caracter As Char In Text

        Index -= 1 'Rest 1 from the Index
        RevText = RevText.Insert(Index, Caracter) '← Put next char in the reversed text

        '↓ Finished reversing the text
        If Index = 0 Then
            RevText = RevText.Replace("§", "") 'Replace char counter to nothing
            Console.WriteLine("Your text reversed: " & RevText) '← When Index its 0 then write the RevText
        End If

    Next

    'Pause
    Console.ReadKey()
```

I've done this project in a console, but you know, you can use this code in a normal Windows Form.
This is my **first Answer** in **Stackoverflow** :)